# How to get selected value index dynamically using ng-options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using select, in which I require selected value and dynamically created index (I don't want to set default to [0] index)
How it can be done.

```
        <div class="input-label">
          Select Mobile
        </div>

        <select ng-model="mobile" ng-options="mobile as mobile.value for mobile in editContactModalData.phoneNumbers"></select>
      </label>

    Above is select option and below is input box where the selected value is set       


      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-show="mobile">
        <input type="tel" maxlength="10" placeholder="mobile" ng-model="mobile.value">
      </label>
```

this is one modal and I want to show these changes of selected mobile in another modal

the second modal consist

```
  <span>{{contact.phoneNumbers[0].value}}</span>
```

so in this in the place of [0] index i want to put dynamically selected value.

Answer (score 1):

@Nikhil: First thing ngOptions doesn't support $index like ng-repeat.

If you needed index of that value than you can try like this.

```
<select 
  ng-model="select"
  ng-options="values.indexOf(selectedItem) as selectedItem for 
selectedItem in values">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change and assign value to contact like

```
<select ng-change="setNumber(mobile)" ng-model="mobile" ng-options="mobile as mobile.value for mobile in editContactModalData.phoneNumbers"></select>
```

In controller just set value:

```
$scope.setNumber = function(num){
```

$scope.contact = num.value;

}

Then this will show in view

```
{{contact}}
```

Comment: the second modal consist of ng-repeat so the given value is set to all contacts.

Comment: Where you are using ng-repeat.

Comment: <ion-item class="item icon-right edit-selection" ng-repeat="contact in modalData"  ng-click="selectUserModal(contact)">
  <span>{{contact}}</span>
  <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-close" ng-click="selectUserModal(contact);" ng-class="selectedClassModal(contact)" ng-style="checkSelectedModal(contact)"></button>
  <button class="button button-icon ion-edit"  ng-click="showEditContactModal(contact,$index);" ></button>
</ion-item>

Comment: oh man then change the variable name I just set as example you can change it.

Comment: yes i have changed it, but still have the same problem

Comment: How's that possible.

Comment: same value is set to all contacts in list